# MS VS test runner exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-test-runner

I always get the following exceptions after my test has already completed, and the test runner is in the process of shutting down. Is this normal? I always feel rather concerned when I get a bunch of random exceptions..

> The thread '' (0xc04) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
>   exceptionvstest.executionengine.exeSystem.AppDomainUnloadedException,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Attempted to
>   access an unloaded AppDomain.
>   System.AppDomainUnloadedException:
>   Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain.
>
> The thread '' (0xdd8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> 'vstest.executionengine.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\CppUnitFramework\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.TestEngine.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\CppUnitFramework\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.Discoverer.dll'
>
> The thread '' (0xa64) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring DTC solved my problem.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q434480

Comment: Absolutely helped!
In case the image will disappear in the future: Goto Control Panel, Admin Tools -> Component Service. In the UI tree on the left choose Console Root -> Component Service -> Computers -> Distributed -> Local DTC, rightclick -> properties. 
In this UI on the tab "Security" toggle the checkboxes on: Allow remove clients, allow remote administration, allow inbound, allow outbound, no authentication required.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very safe thing to do.